# Issues with ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, jquery, templates

I am using an Ajax call with rails to call a method in my controller. My problem is that code itself works fine and I see no errors. When I go to test the code I get

`ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template branch/call_s
ml], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
       * "C:/home/Ruby/rails/showrooms/texting/app/views"
       * "C:/home/Ruby/rails/showrooms/texting/app/views/shared"
       * "C:/home/Ruby/rails/showrooms/texting/app/views"`

this is my controller method.

```
  # Sends a SMS message to selected phone number. 
  # 
  def call_sms
    if current_associate    
      @text_number    = params[:phone_number]
      @text_message   = params[:text_message].to_s
      if !@text_number.empty? && !@text_message.empty?

        @sms = ShortMessagingService.new  
        if @sms.send(@text_number, @text_message)       
          @sms_message = "Status: #{@sms.sent?}"
        end
      else
       @sms_message = 'Phone number and text field cannot be blank.'
     end
   else
     @sms_message = 'You do not have perission for this feature.'
   end
 end
```

this is the route

```
# Small Messaging Service rout. 
post 'call_sms' => 'branch#call_sms'
match 'call_sms' => 'branch#call_sms'
```

this is the form:

```
<%= form_for :call_sms, url: {action: "call_sms"},  
    :method => :post, :remote => true, 
    :html => {:id => 'sms_form'} do |f| 
%> 
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

this is my test

```
  test "Can send sms messages." do
    phone_number  = '18006388875'
    text_message  = "Hey this is a test. Don't text and drive."
    post :call_sms
    assert_response :ok
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is performing an ajax request, but your test case is not.

Instead of `post :call_sms`, try this:

```
xhr :post, :call_sms
```

This tells the test case to send an ajax post instead of a regular post.

Comment: Genius!  need looking for this for days.  Damn interwebs.

Comment: If i add `render :nothing => true`  It does not load  call_sms.js.erb and I get an error in my console

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't realize you did have a js.erb file. In that case, just replace `post :call_sms` in your test case with `xhr :post, :call_sms`.